# How to not freeze UI when using async Task ConfigureAwait(true)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I have a WPF (UI) app that retrieves data from a SQL database on init/load time.
To make the app's startup time fast (and not freeze due to loading the data) i tried doing a couple of things to load the data asynchronously, but with not much luck in terms of the UX i was expecting.

Basically the UI still freezes (even if it is just for a brief moment).

Here's what i've tried:

The method which the data loads is marked with async Task. I invoke this method like this

```
// Note that i use ConfigureAwait(true) because the data is being loaded from the UI.
LoadData().CongigureAwait(true);
```

Here is the method:

```
        private async void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new DataModel.BusinessData())
                {
                    var people= await context.People
                                            .ToListAsync()
                                            .ConfigureAwait(true);

                    foreach (var person in people)
                    {
                        this.People.Add(new PersonItem(person));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw;
            }
        }
```

Now despite the asynchronous nature of this data retrieval, it is being handled back on the main thread (the UI thread). Again, this is being called from the UI (MVVM pattern), so i need this.

**The end result is this:**

I still see a brief moment of UI freezing during startup time.

**Question:**

> How can data be retrieved AND be handled back by the UI thread WITHOUT
>   freezing the UI? Is this even possible when being handled back by the
>   UI thread?

Comment: ConfigureAwait(true) is the default so you shouldn't need this. If I had to guess, is there data binding on that "People" list? How large is that list and how heavy is the UI that binds to that list? If I had to guess, I would say the UI is not freezing because of the call to get the people but instead the UI is struggling to handle one at a time addition of PersonItem.

Comment: In my case, i only have 1-3 People items coming in.

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove the code you were originally asking about. The question must remain as originally stated, edited _only_ for clarifying the question or improving formatting. If you change the question so that the only thing in the question is working code, then the question becomes useless to any future reader, as well as unanswerable. Frankly, the fix you proposed is questionable anyway, but if you really believe it's the answer to your own question, post the new code as an answer and self-accept that answer.

Comment: Sometimes it's the actual panel in the UI that will cause the freeze, Have a look at using VirtualizingStackPanel if your UI can use it, we don't know what controls you're using. And when working with MvvM there should an actual vm involved in all this, which is nowhere to be seen?

Answer (score 1):

It's only the actual call to `ToListAsync` that is asynchronous. The rest of your code executes on the UI thread.

If `People` contains a lot of items, rendering them may be slow.

You could try to assing the `People` property to a new collection instead of adding the items to the data-bound collection one by one:

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    using (var context = new DataModel.BusinessData())
    {
        var people = await context.People.ToListAsync();
        this.People = await Task.Run(() => new ObservableCollection(people.Select(person => new PersonItem(person))));
    }
}
```

Remember to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the People property.

You could also try to execute all code on a background thread in case the implementation of `ToListAsync` actually blocks:

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var context = new DataModel.BusinessData())
        {
            this.People = new ObservableCollection(context.People.Select(person => new PersonItem(person)).ToArray());
        }
    });
}
```

If it's still slow, you need to either decrease the number of items to display or use a faster component to render the items.